# Can't use dynamic variable in aesthetic variables in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use dynamically added column names from a dataframe in aesthetics. Basically trying to use variable names from a separate vector `prm(c("a","b","c"))` decoding to column names in dataframe but `prm[1]/prm[2]` does't work. The following code uses `names()` to obtain column names of last added columns but still doesn't work.

Can someone please help figure out the problem in this code.

```
  rn_s<-subset(rn, rn$ReadScore > 0.1)
  y_count = "..count.."
  d <-ggplot(data=rn_s,
         aes_string(x=names(rn_s)[length(names(rn_s))], y=y_count,
              shape = names(rn_s)[length(names(rn_s))-2],
              colour = factor(rn_s[["Productivity"]]),
              size=1.8),geom="point",stat="bin") +
      facet_grid(paste(". ~ ",prm[2],sep="")) +
      labs(title="ReadCount Distribution by Productivity : Sequencing Quality Metric \n (Filter: ReadScore > 0.1)", y="Counts", x="Sample") +
      guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "Productivity"),
                                   shape = guide_legend(title="Instrument"),
                                   size = guide_legend(NULL)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=PacBioCols)
  show(d)
```

Comment: Please spend some time on creating a **reproducible** and **minimal** example of the problem, so that others would decide spending some time on helping you.

Comment: Hard to tell without an example, but looks like you gave `colour` a vector instead of a column name?

Comment: i don't think `geom="point",stat="bin"` are supposed to be in `ggplot()`; they should be in a layer.